# Why do we say "What do you do for a living"?

Tags: articles, countable-nouns

What does "**a**" (the indefinite article) imply in this context?

Answer (score 4):

In that context, "a living" refers to the subject's profession/job. So, that question is asking:

*What do you do for your profession?*

You can also say things like:

I build houses *for a living*. (Your profession is building houses)

I found this definition for *living*:

```
an income sufficient to live on or the means of earning it.
```

[Source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/living)

The indefinite article is simply referring to the fact that there are multiple things that a person can do for their job. A definite article would imply that there is only a single thing a person can do *to make a living*.

Comment: I found a sample sentence "I mean, I don't like my job but at least it's a living (= a way of earning money)." [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/living_3)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, it is a shortening of the phrase "a living wage."

People will also use this expression to say things like, "It's a living."

But, you can also say "I make my living . . ."

The short answer to your question:  Living in this case is a noun.  And, therefore needs the article to designate it as such, instead of being a verb.

If you asked "What do you do for living?" (Gerund of the verb) The answer would be akin to "Breath, eat, drink, etc."

Comment: If you down vote, please comment.

Comment: This answer comes closer to answering the OP's question than any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Replace omitted words to get a normal and reasonable expression, e.g. "What do you do to earn the money necessary for a decent living?" I think then the shortened expression will be clear.
Of course, that's a long sentence with a lot of words and the question is frequently used. 
So it's no wonder that such a formula gets shortened and everything that is self-evident is omitted.

Comment: I believe the poster understands the idiom, he is asking about the usage of the indefinite article "a".

Comment: I think "a living" is sufficiently explained with the complete formula.

Comment: @rogermue your sentence ended with "a decent living". It doesn't describe the usage of "a". However, I have found the answer. You can look at my comment on Alex W's answer.